# Proxyman seems to be blocking instagram generally

Tags: proxy, proxyman

Proxyman (amazing app BTW) seems to be blocking Instagram login and feed refresh from iOS. Is there a work around for this?

Other domains are proxying just fine. If I turn of the proxy mapping on iOS Instagram works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You're unable to capture HTTPS traffic from Instagram/Facebook/... because they are using SSL Pinning. It prevents MitM apps to intercept unless you have their pinned certificate or jailbreak devices.

Comment: Ah ok. I guess I couldn't tell they were using ssl pinning from proxyman. Thanx for the reply.